# Series and Parallel RLC Circuit

Tags: passive-networks, resonance, coupling, resonant-converter

I am trying to build a resonant circuit for data communication between coils.

Which would be better, a series or a parallel resonant circuit?

What is the difference between them and in which applications should we use them?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=rlc

Answer (score 2):

[Link to Reference](http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/series-resonance-vs-parallel-resonance.html)

**Characteristics of series resonance circuit:**

- Minimum impedance
- Maximum circuit current
- cos(φ) = 1 , hence current and voltage becomes in phase.
- Circuit current becomes proportional to circuit resistance i.e. I ~ 1/R

**Uses of series resonance circuit:**

- As frequency selection circuit in radio and TV tuner circuits.
- As band pass filter circuit.

**Characteristics of parallel resonance circuit:**

- Maximum impedance
- Minimum circuit current
- cos(φ) = 1, hence voltage and current becomes in phase
- Circuit current depends on circuit impedance, Z = L/C or I ~ -(1/R)

**Uses of parallel resonance circuit:**

- As a Band Stop Filter
- As a tank circuit in Oscillators
- As a plate load in IF and RF amplifiers
- As I.F. trap in aerial circuit of radio as well as TV receivers.

[image: comparison chart]